# what is opposite to javascript match()

Tags: javascript

if i want to match some thing with javascript i can use foo.match(); but how can i check if it not match...

Comment: !foo.match() or ^ in match foo.match()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be more explicit, I tend to use `!` and `.test()`, e.g:

```
var hasNoMatch = !/myregex/.test(string);
```

Since since by the spec [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns null in the case of no matches, this works as well:

```
var hasNoMatch = !foo.match();
```

From [the MDC documentation for `.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) (much quicker resource most of the time:

> If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array) containing all matches. If there were no matches, the method returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just testing if a pattern matches, you should use the `test` method as Nick suggested.

If you want to find something that doesn't match the pattern, you can change the pattern to match everything except that. For example using a negative set:

```
// find uppercase characters
var m = s.match(/[A-Z]+/g);

// find everything except uppercase characters
var m = s.match(/[^A-Z]+/g);
```